# Shift Key in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way in GWT to tell if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is down inside of an `onClick()` handler?

For example:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;

public class PanelTileBase implements ClickHandler {

    PanelTileBase()
    {
        addClickHandler(this);
    }

    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        // is the shift key down?
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: i totally don't understand how this great question can have 100 views and 0 upvotes. whiskey tango foxtrot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this (untested)

```
void onClick(ClickEvent ev) {
  NativeEvent nEv = ev.getNativeEvent(); 
  if ( nEv.getShiftKey() ) { 
    // event is true.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And for the **keyboard** API changed, but the idea is the same:

```
if (event.isShiftKeyDown()) {
    // your code                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[GWT KeyEvent API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyEvent.html) has the is{Alt,AnyModifier,Control,Meta,Shift}KeyDown() functions.